# Inline base64-encoded images or HTTP request?

Tags: css, optimization

There are at least two ways to use an image in CSS:

- with an HTTP request;

  url(/path/to/image.png)
- with a data URL.

  url(data:image/png;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_DATA_HERE)

But I was wondering, as base64-encoded data takes 33% more space, therefore 33% more time to load, is it worth it, or should I just make an HTTP request--using a sprite if there're several images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A separate request is almost always preferable because with `data:` URIs,

- it doesn't work in older IEs and is limited to 32k in IE8
- it can be argued that it goes against separation of styling and content
- Style sheet files get blown up, which may cause trouble if the browser's developers never expected CSS files to reach these kinds of sizes

I would use it only when there is no other choice.

Comment: I would say it depends on the conditions. Reducing the HTTP connections can speedup the page loading. For e.g. [rack-pagespeed](http://rack-pagespeed.heroku.com/) is doing it.

Comment: @KARASZI good point - if reducing HTTP connections beats separate cacheability and browser compatibility in a specific scenario, it can be preferable to go with data URIs. Added "almost" to "always"

Comment: using Sass + Compass, you can convert to base64 on compile. I think this is preferable to sprites, because it means that the images stay separate in dev mode. Regarding the caching - the CSS caches, so I don't understand the concern?

Comment: @Matrym  true, the caching concern isn't really valid in this context (it is when you embed stuff into the main page, but not the style sheet). I'll remove that.

Answer (score 4):

The web server should take care of the 33 % more space by GZIP-ing all text files so that should not be that big of a problem. This together with reducing the number of HTTP requests ([which is very important performance-wise](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http)) makes the method worthwhile. Also, the images are still cached but now in the CSS file instead of in separate files.

Preferably the embedding should be done with a build script that inserts the data URIs. That way we don't have to care about large chunks of base64-encoded data when editing the CSS files. Also, remember to have a good solution if images occur more than one time in the file, e.g. re-writing the CSS rules. We don't want the file to be larger than necessary.

There are problems with IE though. IE<=7 can't handle data URIs at all and IE8 can't handle them for larger URIs than 32K. The latter could be solved by simply not embedding too large images (maybe you shouldn't anyway). Regarding IE<=7 the problem can be solved by using MHTML instead and specifying different CSS files for different browsers using IE conditional comments.

Here is a good blog post about embedding images in CSS and how to fix the problems for IE: http://blog.meebo.com/?p=2320

Comment: I find it easier than managing a sprite and indeed incorporated it in my largest site using [MHTML for IE](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/) (IE8 can use this too if required) - the performance on this site increased enormously, though there were a few other measures taken, I would say it definitely has it's place, for smaller images that would normally be sprited. you can repeat a Data Uri image which you can't do with part of a sprite - I don't have a build script but use a separate Scss file for them (like an index) and `@extend` them where required

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would always go with a separate request. I've had trouble in the past with Internet Explorer and data:url images.

It seems IE8 limits url length to 32KB, which is often not enough for images.

[Wikipedia on Browser Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support)